# Salt server on 403 error

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

i have a frontends server with nginx, this serve the static content, and forward by proxy_pass the rest.

I have a problem with the backends servers and this return 403 error randomy, this is in another [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/324421/apache2-nfs4-return-randoms-403).

For a immediately solution, i want only pass if apache return 200, i now have:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/upstreams

```
upstream balanced {
        server 10.15.1.10:80;
        server 10.15.1.11:80;
        server 10.15.1.12:80;
}
```

And in the virtuals:

```
  server {
      access_log  /var/log/nginx/myweb.access.log main buffer=32k;
      error_log   /var/log/nginx/myweb.error.log info;
      #expires     31d;
      #limit_conn  gulag 5;
      listen      80; # rcvbuf=64k backlog=128;
      server_name myweb.com www.myweb.com;

        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;


      location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
                access_log off;
                expires 30d;
                root    /srv/www/myweb/httpdocs;
      }

      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://balanced;
      }
 }
```

I need, in case of 403 response from the backs, try the next. as well as if the server does not respond.

Thanks, sorry my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check on proxy_next_upstream directive... http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_next_upstream

I don´t know if I can handle 403 requests on 1.0.x version, but seems easy to customize the code as shows this patch for 0.6.32 and 0.8.7 versions...
http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,4830